# How to make header sticky using Typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, header, sticky

I'm newer in React dev, I'd like to make the header sticky (index.tsx & styles.ts).

I had tried to use React Hooks: create a sticky component (sticky.tsx & sticky.scss) and use them by inserting the two lines of code `import Sticky from ‘./Sticky’` and `<Sticky top={60}><Header /></Sticky>`in index.tsx but it doesn't works.

if you have any idea, you're welcome.

See the code below:

index.tsx

```html
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export const HeaderSection = styled("header")`
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;

  .ant-row-space-between {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

export const LogoContainer = styled(Link)`
  display: flex;
`;

export const NavLink = styled("div")`
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
`;

export const CustomNavLink = styled("div")`
  width: 203px;
  display: inline-block;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 411px) {
    width: 150px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    width: 118px;
  }
`;

export const ContactWrapper = styled("div")<any>`
  cursor: pointer;
  width: ${(p) => (p.width ? "100%" : "110px")};
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  display: inline-block;
`;

export const Burger = styled("div")`
  @media only screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    display: block;
  }

  display: none;

  svg {
    fill: #2e186a;
  }
`;

export const NotHidden = styled("div")`
  @media only screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const Menu = styled("h5")`
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
`;

export const CustomNavLinkSmall = styled(NavLink)`
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #18216d;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
  margin: 0.5rem 2rem;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    margin: 1.25rem 2rem;
  }
`;

export const Label = styled("span")`
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #404041;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
`;

export const Outline = styled(MenuOutlined)<any>`
  font-size: 22px;
`;

export const Span = styled("span")`
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

  &:hover,
  &:active,
  &:focus {
    color: rgb(255, 130, 92);
    text-underline-position: under;
    text-decoration: rgb(255, 130, 92) wavy underline;
  }
`;
```

styles.ts

```html
import { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Drawer } from "antd";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import Container from "../../common/Container";
import { SvgIcon } from "../../common/SvgIcon";
import { Button } from "../../common/Button";
import {
  HeaderSection,
  LogoContainer,
  Burger,
  NotHidden,
  Menu,
  CustomNavLinkSmall,
  Label,
  Outline,
  Span,
} from "./styles";

const Header = ({ t }: any) => {
  const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDrawer = () => {
    setVisibility(!visible);
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    setVisibility(!visible);
  };

  const MenuItem = () => {
    const scrollTo = (id: string) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLDivElement;
      element.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
      setVisibility(true);
    };
    return (
      <>
        
        <CustomNavLinkSmall onClick={() => scrollTo("product")}>
          <Span>{t("product")}</Span>
        </CustomNavLinkSmall>
        <CustomNavLinkSmall onClick={() => scrollTo("about")}>
          <Span>{t("about")}</Span>
        </CustomNavLinkSmall>
        <CustomNavLinkSmall onClick={() => scrollTo("mission")}>
          <Span>{t("mission")}</Span>
        </CustomNavLinkSmall>
        <CustomNavLinkSmall
          style={{ width: "180px" }}
          onClick={() => scrollTo("contact")}
        >
          <Span>
            <Button>{t("Contact")}</Button>
          </Span>
        </CustomNavLinkSmall>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <HeaderSection>
      <Container>
        <Row justify="space-between">
          <LogoContainer to="/" aria-label="homepage">
            <SvgIcon src="logo.svg" width="101px" height="64px" />
          </LogoContainer>
          <NotHidden>
            <MenuItem />
          </NotHidden>
          <Burger onClick={showDrawer}>
            <Outline />
          </Burger>
        </Row>
        <Drawer closable={false} visible={visible} onClose={onClose}>
          <Col style={{ marginBottom: "2.5rem" }}>
            <Label onClick={onClose}>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Menu>Menu</Menu>
              </Col>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Outline />
              </Col>
            </Label>
          </Col>
          <MenuItem />
        </Drawer>
      </Container>
    </HeaderSection>
  );
};

export default withTranslation()(Header);
```

sticky.tsx

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import './Sticky.scss';

interface StickyProps {
    child: React.ReactChild,
    top: number,
}

const  Sticky: React.FunctionComponent<StickyProps> = (child, top) => {
  const [isSticky, setSticky] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add scroll event when the component is loaded
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
    // Remove scroll event after the component is unmount,
    // like componentWillUnmount()
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => handleScroll);
    };
    // Here, we set useEffect() arguments as empty array.
    // This means useEffect() will only run once after component loaded
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    // Make sure ref has current attibute and getBoundingClientRect function
    // otherwise, it could cause getBoundingClientRect undefined error.
    if (ref && ref.current && ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()) {
        // Then, we compare the distance of the ref component to the top
        // with top value we set. If less than, we set isStick ture.
        setSticky(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top <= top);
    }
  };

  return (
      <div className={`sticky__wrapper ${isSticky && 'sticky'}`} ref={ref}>
        <div className="sticky--inner">
            {child}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default Sticky
```

sticky.scss

```html
.sticky__wrapper {
    position: relative;
    // height: 4rem; /* probably you need to set height value for wrapper */
  }
  
.sticky .sticky--inner {
    position: fixed;
    // top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Post JSfiddle or codeshare link if you have more code, which will help other developers to find the issue and provide a solution for your problem

Comment: Post JSfiddle.net or codeshare.io link if you have more code, which will help other developers to find the issue and provide a solution for your problem

Comment: Notice that style.ts is the index code and index.tsx is the style code

Answer (score 0):

Note that you confused the document names in your post.

Go to: src\components\Header\styles.ts

find lines:

```
export const HeaderSection = styled("header")`
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
```

and add below:

```
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
```

To get:

```
export const HeaderSection = styled("header")`
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  .ant-row-space-between {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }

`;
```

Adjust `background-color: yourfavoritecolor;` to your needs.

`z-index: 1;` brings the HeaderSection to the front. Otherwise, your content would scroll over the HeaderSection.